# Include header and meta tags with php

Tags: php, html, search, seo, meta

I know that searching engines look for metatags in the html header when they search for websites, so I was wondering if I include the metatags in my pages using php would it affect how my web pages will be find?

Comment: Your tags will be rendered as HTML, so that shouldn't affect it. Look at your (rendered) HTML source, that will give you an indication. Use the w3 validator https://validator.w3.org/

Comment: Please, be more specific what do you use. For example, if you use WordPress or other large CMS, it could be solved with single SEO plugin. Otherwise, you have to generate dynamic metadata within PHP. Thera are some libraries to help, for example [Open-Graph-Tools](https://github.com/niallkennedy/open-graph-protocol-tools)

Comment: I'm not using any of the ones you listed, but I like the dynamic generation idea. I was gonna do one metatags for all my pages, it seems like a bad idea though.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it will help. Typically you might use some of the content from the page to generate the meta-tags. There are character limits to the tags, so make sure you cut off the content before you over-run. I always used to have a standard format, with some constant content (like site title, or section name) plus a variable content generated page by page.